# I'm American marrying an Italian who works in Denmark. We plan to live in Denmark. Do I apply for a "Residence Permit" or "Family Reunification"?

Tags: usa, resident-permit, marriage, eu-spouses, italy

We plan to get married in Denmark and this seems fairly easy, but then we're a bit confused.

- After obtaining our marriage license what is the next step?
- Do I need to apply for a "Residence Permit" or "Family Reunification" in Denmark?
- Also, can this process be completed while I am on a Tourist Schengen Visa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are married, you will become a beneficiary of the EU's [directive on freedom of movment](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616).  The English name for the document you'll need is a *residence card.*  You should not need a visa.  (And you won't normally have a "tourist Schengen visa" because you will have entered as a visa-exempt visitor.)

If you look at the page [Family Reunification](http://usa.um.dk/en/travel-and-residence/family-reunification/) on the website of the Danish Ministry of Foreign Affairs, you will see this:

> Please note that special rules apply to EU/EEA citizens and Swiss citizens residing in Denmark under the EU regulations on free movement. Read more under [EU and Nordic Citizens](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-GB/You-want-to-apply/Family/Family-reunification-with-EU-citizen).

Following the link takes you to a page that explains the requirements in some depth.  It notes that you can apply at the State Administration, but the link there is not currently working.  However, a little searching led me to [EU residence as a family member to an EU citizen](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-GB/You-want-to-apply/Residence-as-a-Nordic-citizen-or-EU-or-EEA-citizen/EU-Family-member-EU-citizen) on the "New to Denmark" site, which should be of help.

As far as I can tell, you should probably apply for the residence card within 90 days of entering Denmark, and you should get married within 90 days of entering the Schengen area.  If I were you, I would try to get married at least a few weeks before the 90 days are up, and then apply for the residence card on the first working day after the wedding.  If you're planning to honeymoon outside the Schengen area, though, you might approach it differently.

Comment: Thanks Phoog!  I've read that page about Family Reunification.  There is a separate page for applying for the <a href="https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-GB/You-want-to-apply/Family/Accompanying-family-members/Accompanying-family---work" title="Residence Permit">Residence Permit</a> when accompanying a family member working in Denmark.  It appears to be 2 different application processes, Residence Permit and Family Reunification.  Are you saying that after marriage I only need to apply for a Residence Permit?

Comment: @benottoman Yes.  You are supposed to pick only one of the options at https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-GB/You-want-to-apply/Family.  The page you link to is for people whose family members are not in Denmark on the basis of EU free movement law.  The residence card (not "residence permit") allows you to live and work in Denmark, so there is no point in applying for another document.

Comment: @benottoman the Danish pages use the term "residence document" rather than "residence card," but the point is that the document does not represent a *grant of permission* to reside in Denmark; rather it is evidence of your *right* to live there, which flows the EU treaties, your spouse's Italian nationality, and your relationship to your spouse.  That is why it is not called a "residence permit."

Comment: thanks for all of the effort, I really appreciate it.  Just to be super clear, after marrying you're saying that I only need to follow the application process for the resident document found under "EU residence as a family member to an EU citizen"...is this correct?

Comment: @benottoman yes, that's correct.  That document gives you a right to live and work in Denmark as long as your spouse lives there under EU free movement law.  It can't be refused except on limited grounds (of public health, public safety, or public policy). The other application reflects requirements, such as financial thresholds, that will not apply to you after you are married.